# For $X$ normed, $Y$ Banach, $T: X \rightarrow Y$ $\exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $B(0,\delta) \subset \overline{T(B(0,1))}$. Why $Y$ Banach?

Tags: functional-analysis

For $X$ normed, $Y$ Banach, $T: X \rightarrow Y$ $\exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $B(0,\delta) \subset \overline{T(B(0,1))}$.

Why must $Y$ be Banach?

---

Is it because of wanting to apply Baire's category theorem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the result is not true as stated. if $T$ is the zero operator we get a  contradiction. It is true if $T$ is surjective or its range is complete. And Baire Category Theorem gives the result when this condition is satisfied.